# How to crop an image when the window is resized HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, size

I have to do a website with HTML/CSS and I have this image that is wider than the page, but I only want it to take the space on the right of the page no more.

Here is my code : `<img src=".\styleCSS\images\Image_menu.jpg" style="float: right; background-size: cover; height : 100%; width: auto; position : absolute; left : 60.7%">`

And here is a picture of what the image looks like on the website. I don't want the scrollbar on the bottom. And I want the picture to adapt its width with the window and stop at the redline I drew.

Can you help me please ?
[image: picture of website]

Answer (score 0):

Put the image inside a div and give the image div and the div of the content on the left a width of desired viewport percentage (maybe 60:40) in vw unit . Eg: width: 60vw;

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your overflow on the x axis.

The [overflow-x and overflow-y](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) properties specifies whether to change the overflow of content just horizontally or vertically (or both).

`overflow-x` specifies what to do with the left/right edges of the content.

overflow hidden - The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible

```html
<img src=".\styleCSS\images\Image_menu.jpg" style="float: right; background-size: cover; height : 100%; width: auto; overflow-x:hidden; position : absolute; left : 60.7%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

And you can also use:  `width: 100%; height: auto;` in img tag.